# Is there a better way to compare each property of a user defined class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Currently I have compare methods for twelve different classes doing something like this:

```
foreach (form_Result R in FinalResult)
{
    if (R.exists == true)
    {
        int goldenIndex = goldenTable.FindIndex(a => a.form_id.Equals(R.form_id));
        int testIndex = testTable.FindIndex(b => b.form_id.Equals(R.form_id));

        if (goldenTable[goldenIndex].form_id == testTable[testIndex].form_id)
        {
            result.Add(new CompareResult
            {
                expectedValue = goldenTable[goldenIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                actualValue = testTable[testIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                passFail = "Passed"
            });
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(new CompareResult
            {
                expectedValue = goldenTable[goldenIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                actualValue = testTable[testIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                passFail = "Failed"
            });
        }
```

I go on to do this for every property.  In my above example it's "form_id".  In this one class alone I have 26 properties.  Some int, some string, some double, some bool, etc...

I write out this same stretch of code for each property.  Is there an easier way to go about doing this?   I keep thinking that there must be some way to do a foreach loop here.  Or is there a better way?

Comment: You could serialise the source and traget objects and compare them

Comment: Is reflection an option? If so, you could use it to enumerate through the properties on each of the `FinalResult` classes.

Comment: I've never used reflection before.  Should I consider it?

Comment: Also, your if...else is not very elegant. you can do something like this:
`string PassFail = "Failed";
    if(condition) {
      PassFail = "Passed";
    }

    result.Add(new CompareResult
            {
                expectedValue = goldenTable[goldenIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                actualValue = testTable[testIndex].form_id.ToString(),
                PassFail
            });`

Comment: I've used the Compare .NET Objects Assembly that's licensed under the Microsoft Public License to do deep object comparisons.  https://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/